# Set circles over images to know there is a gallery

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have a group of images which are shown just one by one in a img tag. Whenever you press over the image, it changes to the next one.

I want to add something over it to make people to know there are more images, a bunch of circles or something similar. Is it possible? How can I do it? I am not english and I don't know how they are called in english so I can't make any succesful search on internet.

This is my working example: http://jsfiddle.net/kZp7V/ Don't look about the change of the images as they will be equals at the end. I found those images on internet for the example.

HTML code:

```
 <div><img id="EJ_test" onclick='image(this)' src="http://www.fundacionsantandercreativa.com/ekh2983gd29837gt_uploads/web_2/localizaciones_images/image_localizacion_final_37_2012-02-28_16_04_33.jpg" class="croptest"></div>
```

Javascript code:

```
    var counterImage = 0;
    var ccI = new Array('http://tiendas.fnac.es/la-canada/files/2010/12/Peque%C3%B1a-orquesta-mediterr%C3%A1neo-300x286.jpg',
                        'http://muack.es/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/smalldata1.jpg',
                        'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/604644048/sign051.gif'
                        );
window.image = function(element){
    if(counterImage < 3){
        document.getElementById("EJ_test").setAttribute('src', ccI[counterImage]);
        counterImage++;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("EJ_test").setAttribute('src', ccI[0]);
        counterImage = 1;
    }


}
```

CSS code:

```
.croptest{

width: 80%;
height: auto;
   overflow: hidden;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.4);

-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
border-radius: 6px;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another `div` with absolute positioning and place everything you want there.
See the example: http://jsfiddle.net/jMg55/

Comment: It is a good idea. But I should add many css classes depending on which I want to set in other colour. And its possition to the left. I will try

Comment: I did this: http://jsfiddle.net/jMg55/2/ I think it is enough for the moment. I will check the way to create it dinamically because for the moment I just have 3 or 4 images but if one day I have 20... Thank man.

Comment: I already gave you the ok because it works. But I can't be able to use it with my jquery mobile webpage. I am still trying because I think it has to be something wrong with styles... If I find the answer I will write here for next user with problems

Comment: I've updated your html and css a bit so it looks more like real life code now: http://jsfiddle.net/52Jbd/

Usually no color classes are used and there's only one additional `active` class to highlight the image that is being showed right now. But if you really need some more, you may add some other classes like `red`.

Comment: Now it is perfect. It appears in my jquery mobile page without problems. Thank you, indeed.